# iOS Oblique TextView scrolling in Cocos2D or native

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uitextview

How to make UITextView scrolling when text is not vertical?

Like

```
      +--------------+
     / Text         /
    / Here         /
   / Is           /
  / Not          /
 / Vertical     /
+--------------+
```

Where starts of lines are in the same angle as border (background) image.
Or we can use another element than UITextView if it can solve the problem.

Scrolling only in vertical direction,
Background image is fixed,
No, visible is only part which fits to shape, other is hidden

Screen is covered by private license, I can't publish it.

Comment: Would be great if you could specify what you mean exactly by scrolling, do you need to scroll vertically or horizontally? Does the text have to scroll over a fixed background? Is the entire text always visible on the screen or are parts hidden? Maybe also post a screenshot of thats possible, honestly don't quite get the question (and considering that nobody answered so far I am probably not the only one)

Comment: Sure, I edited question to add these informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skew the textfield by using this code:

```
float angle = -20.0/180*M_PI;
CATransform3D skew = CATransform3DIdentity;
skew.m21 = tanf(angle);
textField.layer.transform = skew;
```

EDIT: perhaps I've misunderstood your question- you want straight text, but oblique scrolling? If that's the case, you can put your UITextField (or UITextView) into a UIScrollView, but give the scrollView the opposite transform to your textField, like so

```
float angle = -20.0/180*M_PI;
CATransform3D skew = CATransform3DIdentity;

skew.m21 = tanf(-angle);
scrollView.layer.transform = skew;

skew.m21 = tanf(angle);
textField.layer.transform = skew;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want the text view to scroll along a diagonal? It's not the most elegant solution but something like this perhaps:

1. Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method
2. Get the existing `contentOffset` at each delegate callback
3. Modify the `x`-value of the offset to an amount that corresponds to the amount of "diagonal-ness" you want to go in
4. `[scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:NO];`

Also set the scroll view's `directionalLockEnabled` to NO.